# Singletons alternative

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a pretty simple game engine. It uses several singletons(I'll enumerate some of them).

```
Resource Manager
Render Engine
Events Manager
Factory
etc
```

These singletons have many calls from one to another. I'll take Events Manager sample usage:

1. Any object derived from Listener can add itsel as a listener for some events just like this `EventsManager->RegisterListener(this, &SomeClass::SomeMethod);` (event type is deduced by SomeMethod parameter)
2. Any other object can fire an event like this `EventsManager->PushEvent(SomeEvent);`

After some synchronization the event reaches to all listeners. This is very a simple usage for EventsManager when it is singleton.

Similar behavior is with other singletons. I want to remove the singletons, but my main problem is that I want to keep the code simple to use from the "user point of view" as it is now. I read some techniques of doing this, but most of the make the initialization/usage of the classes more complicated. I know this topic was discused many times on SO, but no answer is appropriate for my programming philosophy - to keep everything as simple as possible.

I don't want to have complicated definition/initialization for my classes like:

```
SomeClass<EventManager, RenderEngine,...>
```

or

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(EventsManager, RenderEngine...)
```

Can you please give me some advice on this topic?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the singletons ?

Comment: i'm thinking, instead of having all these singletons at namespace scope, have the instances in an object (of which there will ordinarily only be one, except maybe for testing). then as you get that to work, think about more divide-and-conquer. possibly.

Comment: Yes, why do you want to remove the singletons?  They might be the most appropriate pattern.

Comment: In keeping with your philospohy, I have always felt that if you want to ensure there's only one instance of an object in your application then the simplest thing to do is just create one.

Comment: @giorashc My last problem with singletons was with memory leaks detection. I override new/delete and I want to dump at "the end" the allocated memory that was not deleted. Can you please tell me when is "the end" in this kind of environment?

Comment: I think we still try to understand what you want to do (and why). If you don't know "the end" in this environment - what is it in the "other" environments?

Comment: "the end" is where you put it, pretty much. If you're using `static xxx` then the end isn't exactly defined, but it's after your main() function returns. Alternatively you can give your singleton a cleanup() function and simply call it just before your main() returns. That being said, I'd stick to singletons too. If you're having trouble with memory leaks or similar it's a problem with how you use singletons, not a fundamental problem. The classes you've got there are very nice examples for good singletons.

Comment: @Zane This was my last problem with singletons. If you don't use global like variables "the end" of a program might be the last line from main. I didn't have only this problem, it was just a simple sample. I don't want to discuss about initialization order, thread safety and other problems I encountered.

Comment: Hi @Felics, Usually you do not delete a singleton, its whole purpose is to reside through your entire program's runtime evnironment. The OS will cleanup your overleft data in the memory space provided for the program (Not sure on the last one but think I read it somewhere once looking for a similar solution)

Comment: Another thing, if your singleton does lots of allocations maybe pass the allocation/deletion responsibilities to another entity in your program. (sort of like a garbage collector for deleting these allocation which you say were not deleted)

Comment: @giorashc But how can I know if the leak is from a singleton or from other place?:) Is not simple to look at 1000 leaks and say if they are from singletons or not:)

Comment: @Felics Easy, but requires some work. Disable the singleton (comment out all calls to it or render it unusable so you can be sure it doesn't leak) and see if the leaks go away. Alternatively, there are also memory debugging tools available (sometimes inside your IDE already) which you can use. Those track where and when you've allocated the non-deallocated memory blocks.

Comment: @s3rius And how can I run the game for one hour let's say to check leaks with all singletons disabled?:)

Comment: That very much depends on how your code looks like. For example I'm trying to code in a way where I can easily switch out components. I could take one of my singletons and just insert a dummy version. My code is robust enough that it survives without Events/Resources/etc. But if that's not an option you can still use a memory debugger :) PS: Or you go hunting. A memory leak can only appear where you've previously allocated something. Just go and see for yourself where and when your code calls allocs. If it's a 1-man project then you should have enough knowledge of your code to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a global "game" object that creates an instance of each of the classes that are currently singletons

For the specific example of your EventManager; your Listener base class could provide implementations of a register method and a push method that derived classes can call.

A skeleton definition:

```
class Listener
{
public:
    virtual void ReceiveMessage( ... ) = 0;

protected:
    void Register()
    {
        GetEventManagerSomehow()->RegisterListener( this, etc );
    }

    void PushEvent( etc )
    {
        GetEventManagerSomehow()->PushEvent( etc );
    }

}
```

Comment: The "hub" idea is pretty nice for my problem. In this way I have only one singleton, the "hub" and everything is created/destroyed here and can be accesed through the "hub". Combined to Mark Ransom proposal I can delete the "hub" at "the end" or I can know for sure that in "hub" destructor I don't have any global variable left.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the specific problem of detecting resource leaks in your singletons, give each singleton class a shutdown method that destroys the instance.

```
class Singleton
{
    // ...
    static Singleton * GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == NULL)
            instance = new Singleton;
        return instance;
    }
    static void Shutdown()
    {
        delete instance;
        instance = NULL;
    }
    static Singleton * instance;
};

Singleton * Singleton::instance = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but maybe too long for a comment.

[Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is a very good alternative to singletons: You create instances in the main function of your program and you pass them to "modules" (which are main classes), so they can use them locally.  This means that for these classes you will have the "complicated" constructors that you don't want.
However, The complexity should only be limited to some classes and passing some dependent "modules" are in my point of view not that complex.  As a bonus, you can find out dependencies between modules by just looking at the constructors or at the main function.

Dependency injection is used a lot because it does solve the issue that you are seeing (and more, like unit testing) with only a very limited amount of added complexity.

Comment: I read about dependecy injection before posting this question and I have one problem(events manager again:P): How can I use PushEvent from any class from any module without sending a reference of EventsManager to these classes? Maybe there is something I didn't undertand in this pattern

Comment: The most straightforward way is to pass the reference to the constructors.  However, this should only be done to some main classes.  Smaller classes can retrieve references as needed from their "manager classes", so the injection doesn't have to go to each and every class.

Comment: This will make the code inconsistent. In one class one will have to use SomeManager1->GetEventManager->PushEvent and in other class one will have to use SomeManager2->GetEventManager->PushEvent. This also will make some classes usable just from one part of the code(the "manager class" is different").

Comment: This is not inconsistent if you look at it from a module point of view (the program is split up in functional parts containing there own set of submodules and classes).  If your program is monolytic and you value consistency over modulation, then there could be one main class-manager that can be accessed (as in user1158692).  You could also extend dependency injection to each class that needs the reference.  This is a design choice and that is up to you.